# dateFormat in multiDatesPicker not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker, jquery-multidatespicker

It's a big issue with jqueryui datepicker and getting no solution.

```
$('#datepicker').multiDatesPicker({
    dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
    mode: 'daysRange',
    dayNamesMin: ['S', 'M', 'T', 'W', 'T', 'F', 'S'],
    autoselectRange: [-1,2],
});
```

error: 
***Uncaught Unexpected literal at position 2***

Comment: what version of Jquery you are using?

Comment: jQuery UI - v1.11.4  and  jquery - jquery-1.11.3

Comment: Same issue here, any solution on this?

Comment: No still not any solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it the complete code you're using to initialize the calendar ?

I had to match the value of dateFormat with the dates I supplied for initializing the datepicker. In my case it was the value of addDates

I changed it to follow the exact format I need for dateFormat and it worked.

Example code:

```
<script>
var today = new Date();
var y = today.getFullYear();
$('#create-calendar').multiDatesPicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    addDates: ['2017-02-22', '2017-03-19'],
    numberOfMonths: [3,2],
    defaultDate: today,
});
</script>
```